# I cannot access state or setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update `state.messages` array from `readFromFile` method which is giving me  **Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined** error. But I logged `this` within that method where I can see `state`. What am I missing?

Also, I want to add an object to `this.state.messages` from `readFromFile` method (when I get a response back from API). How can I do that?

I looked for a solution and all I found was the issue with binding (which I did)

```
class Main extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.readFromFile = this.readFromFile.bind(this);
    // this.readFromFile = this.readFromFile.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    count: 0,
    messages: [{type: 'sent', content: "test1"}, {type: 'received', content: "test2"}],
    inputText: ''
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <span>{ this.renderMessage() }</span>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.inputText} onChange={this.handleTextInput} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSendClick}>Send</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  handleTextInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({inputText: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSendClick = () => {
    console.log(this);
    if (this.state.inputText === "read") {
      this.readFromFile();
      // this log works fine
      console.log(this.state.messages);
    }

    // const { count } = this.state;
    // return count === 0 ? <h1>Zero</h1> : count;
  }

  readFromFile = () => {
    console.log(this);
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/read')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson.content);
        // update NOT WORKING
        // this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat({content: myJson.content, type: 'received'})})
        // this log gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
        // console.log(this.state.messages);
      });
  }

  renderMessage() {
    if (this.state.messages.length === 0) return <p>No message found!</p>;
    return <ul>{this.state.messages.map((msg, idx) => <li key={idx}>{msg.content}</li>)}</ul>;
  }

}

export default Main;
```

Comment: use arrow function here: `.then((myJson) => {` because fetch is a async call to access the correct context inside `.then` callback, you need to bind the `.then` callback method.

Comment: @MayankShukla Thank you it works. Can you please explain cause of the issue?

Comment: you used arrow function with `readFromFile`, that's why `this` is available, and fetch is async call, so use `arrow function` with `.then` callback to access the correct this inside callback function.

Comment: arrow function bind it to context implicitly. That is why you can access **this** inside that function as it is bind to that context.

Comment: @MayankShukla Hi, can you please check my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872356/post-request-using-fetch-not-working) question?