# POST request using fetch not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to do a post call from my react application using below code.

```
  writeToFile = (data = {}) => {
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/write";
    console.log(data);
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
        body: JSON.stringify({"content": "some content"})
      }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

However, it gives me below given error:

[image]

The same request is working in postman (API testing application). This is an `application/json` type request and expects same type of response.

Edit 1:

This is how the request looks on POSTMAN:
[image]

In same application `GET` request(below code) is working fine:

```
  readFromFile = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/read')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((myJson) => {
        console.log(myJson.content);
        this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat({content: myJson.content, type: 'received'})});
        console.log(this.state.messages);
      });
  }
```

Relevant server side code:

```
function writeToFile(request, response) {
    var body = '';

    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
        // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
        if (body.length > 1e6)
            request.connection.destroy();
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        // const dataToWrite = JSON.parse(body)["content"];
        // console.log(dataToWrite);
        myFileModule.fileWriter(JSON.parse(body)["content"]);
        response = allowCORS(response);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        response.write(JSON.stringify({ content: "success..." }));
        response.end();
    });
}

function postRequestHandler(request, response) {

    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch (path) {
        case '/write':
            writeToFile(request, response);
            break;
        default:
            response = allowCORS(response);
            response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.write(JSON.stringify({ content: "Path not defined" }));
            response.end();
            break;
    }
}


function allowCORS(response) {
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // If needed
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // If needed
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Seems CORS issue? What message are you getting via Postman?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati updated my question. Added snippet of post request using postman app.

Comment: is your API server and the client application is running on different host:port ? also, what you are using on backend server (nodejs?). May be you need to allow CORS from backend

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Yes. Server is on `post:8000` while client app is on `port:3000`. I'm also doing `get request` elsewhere in the same application which is working fine. I'm facing issue with post request only. In my Node.js back end application I've allowed CORS, that's why get request is working.

Comment: Which framework your API server is using?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati API server  is using plain node.js

Comment: with express as the framework? or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178114/discussion-between-suresh-prajapati-and-noobie).

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Not using any external framework, only Node.js

Comment: You need to share your backend code to enable CORS or if enabled then may be you have to check why it's returning 404 (maybe something missed)

Comment: Your `allowCORS` function should run for each request before it reaches to any handler(here - `writeToFile`). So that `OPTIONS` req succeed with all required header and browser then will initiate `POST` req

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `http` module to create server, try :

```
var server;
server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    // Set CORS headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // ...
});
```